# VB>NET Backgroundworker ListView

Tags: vb.net, listview, delegates

I'm using a backgroundworker in VB.NET. But I can't add a list item through a delegate. All I'm trying to do is load a ListView with images that I have. What I can't do is load the picture into the listview... ANyhelp with delegates would be grateful/

Delegates, Listview, VB

Here's my code. (For a working Delegate)

```
            Dim delUpdateStatusLabelMessage As DelegateUpdateStatusLabelMessage
            delUpdateStatusLabelMessage = New DelegateUpdateStatusLabelMessage(AddressOf UpdateStatusLabelMessage)
            delUpdateStatusLabelMessage.Invoke("Searching " & lstPagePosts.Count & " posts...")

Private Delegate Sub DelegateUpdateStatusLabelMessage(text As String)
Private Sub UpdateStatusLabelMessage(text As String)
    ToolStripStatusLabelMessage.Text = text
End Sub
```

How can I add an Image to the ListView?

Comment: So you have code that doesn't work and ask for help, Fine, but how we can help if we don't see the not working code?

Comment: In the official documentation you can find a very descriptive sample code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx Read this carefully, test the code and you will understand perfectly how to use it. Asking random issues (and/or putting random pieces of code together) without having these ideas clear would be a waste of time for everyone.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use it. Don't -1 me please! :)

Comment: FYI, I only downvote over-rated questions (where the OP has already got various undeserved upvotes). But if you don't like getting downvotes you shouldn't write these comments (are kind of a magnet for downvoters :)); or if you consider that your question is not helping anyone, just delete it.

Comment: You dont "add an image to the listview", you use an ImageList component and then set the ImageKey of the ListViewItem to indicate which image.

Comment: The whole point of the `BackgroundWorker` is to avoid invoking delegates.  Do the background work in the `DoWork` event handler and then update the UI in the `ProgressChanged` and/or `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.  If you're not doing that then using a `BackgroundWorker` at all is pointless.